# Using PLL as resonance tracker

Tags: pll, vco, resonator

**Edit:** Re-re-formulated :)
I'm developing a resonant circuit with its resonant frequency around 3 GHz. I am constantly tuning this resonance frequency by an unknown amount. How can I read out the resonant frequency?
At first, my idea was to do a frequency sweep through the resonator, feed the response into a log amplifier and sample its output into a uC. Then, by fitting the curve in software, derive the resonant peak.
Is there a cheaper/less cumbersome way to find out the resonator's resonant frequency, e.g. in hardware?

**Edit:** I re-formulated this question:
I'm developing a resonant circuit with its resonance frequency around 3 GHz. I am constantly tuning this resonance frequency. Is it possible to lock to the frequency of resonance with a PLL, so I can somehow read out the frequency the PLL is locked to?

---

I'm developing a resonant circuit with its resonance frequency around 3 GHz. I am able to modify this resonance frequency. Is it possible to track the frequency of resonance with a PLL like the MAX2871 or ADF4355? The [MAX2871 datasheet](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX2871.pdf) provides a block diagram and a schematic that connects CP_OUT with TUNE through the loop filter. How would I connect the output of the resonator back into the PLL to let it lock on that resonance frequency? Or is it simply not possible with a chip like this?

Comment: Explain what you mean by "track the frequency of resonance". Do you want to make a feedback loop that will regulate the resonance frequency of your resonator? **You cannot do that with these ICs**. These ICs are PLLs, they work with a fixed, known, frequency at their input (REFin) which is then used to generate a new signal (using an on-chip oscillator) which is a multiple of that frequency. Example: REFin = 25 MHz, N = 100 => RFout = 2500 MHz.

Comment: I want to detect the resonance frequency of the resonator, I don't need to control it. Anyway, you answered my question by confirming what I already thought. Bedankt!

Comment: Oh, wait, but you said "track"; so I assumed you want to do something else! For frequency detection, you don't need a PLL, you need a frequency detector... So, my answer addresses your literal question, but not what you meant to ask!

Comment: At first, I wanted to sweep a frequency through the resonator to detect the resonant frequency with something like a log amp. But wouldn't it be 'easier' to use a PLL to lock to the resonant frequency of the resonator?

Comment: *I want to detect the resonance frequency of the resonator* You just want to measure the frequency? Then use a "prescaler" IC which is a very fast counter-like circuit that divides the input frequency by a certain number. Example: 3096 MHz in-divide by 1024 gives 3 MHz out, that 3 MHz can then easily be measured using a frequency counter or oscilloscope. (1024 = 2^10 , the chip would use 10 divide-by-two circuits in series).

Comment: Yes, I want to measure the peak of the resonance frequency of the resonator (assuming it's Q-factor is high enough). Isn't that called 'tracking' or am I using the word wrongly? It would be nice to use a PLL for that. Maybe I can measure the phase-error voltage to derive the lock-frequency.

Comment: yes, I think you might be using the word incorrectly :) So, maybe un-accept my answer? It's really not what you're looking for! Please fully describe what you want to do :)

Comment: I edited the main question. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks! So, now the question becomes: do you *really* want a PLL in there? I don't see how this helps your actual goal, determining the frequency of strongest resonance.

Comment: Exactly! I think using a PLL is the cheaper option over using a log detector or something like that, but only if that works at all. Is the proposed idea of using a PLL to determine the resonant frequency a feasible method?

Comment: a PLL is no solution at all to measure a frequency; it can't do that.

Comment: *Is it possible to lock to the frequency of resonance with a PLL, so I can somehow read out the frequency the PLL is locked to?* You should **forget** about the PLL! Instead, explain **what you're trying to achieve**. I give you a "magic black box' with inputs and outputs, it can do anything you describe, what does it need to do? Describe that. By mentioning PLL you go in the "solution" direction but a PLL is probably not the proper solution. So why mention it? Step 1 is to get the problem clear then we can give help finding a solution. That may or may not include (part of) a PLL.

Comment: And don't worry about re-re-formulate your question again, that's OK. Asking a question isn't always easy so no worries, we might get there in the end :-)

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie for your help, I re-re-formulated it. At first, I wasn't sure the question would be specific enough, hence the proposal of using a PLL.

Comment: Is your resonant circuit resonating by itself all the time (at least, when you want to know the frequency)? If so you can feed the 3 GHz signal into my "magic box" and I'll give it a display that will tell you the frequency. Would that do the job or is more needed?

Comment: The 3GHz signal does have to go through the resonator. The 'magic box' needs to be adjacent to the resonator.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to track the frequency of resonance with a PLL

Yes, that's very literally what PLLs do! As long as

- frequency of oscillator is monotonous with voltage applied and
- you can observe the oscillation as voltage,

a PLL chip should do; however:

> PLL like the MAX2871 or ADF4355?

these aren't *PLLs* by themselves, but voltage-controlled oscillators with an integrated PLL.

You'd want your resonant circuit to replace the VCO, so these ICs are not an option, unless you can "bypass" the VCO completely.